# Is it inappropriate to shout for a bus driver to open the door during commute?

Tags: unprofessional-behavior, commute

Every day I commute to work using a bus like this:

[image: articulated bus with four doors]

As I understand it, the bus driver has separate buttons to either actively open the doors or to merely "release" them. If the bus driver only releases the doors, they remain closed and the passengers have to press a button to open a door and get off.

Every now and then a bus driver forgets to release the doors and only actively opens the two doors in the forward half of the bus. Passengers from the rear get over this problem by either quickly walking along the aisle and disembarking through the open front door, or by calling to the bus driver to open the door for them.

But during rush hour, the bus is tightly packed. There are so many people on the bus that, if the bus driver forgets to release the doors, it is impossible for people to move to another door before that door closes and the bus drives on to the next stop. And given the sound-absorbing wall of bodies and the noise, the bus driver will not hear someone calling in the back of the bus.

All of this is not a problem for me, as I get off at the last stop where the bus driver waits for everyone. But every now and then I witness someone who tries to open the unreleased door for a few seconds in vain, then calls, usually in a timid voice, and is not heard, then struggles through the throng a few steps towards the open front door, when that door closes and they have to wait till the next stop and walk back from there to where they actually wanted to go. I imagine that some of them miss the train they want to catch and have a bad start into their work day because of that.

Now today, when the bus driver forgot to release the door, one man politely called for the driver to please open the door, which the bus driver did not react to, and then the *bellowed* in the loudest voice I ever heard, twice, "open the door!", until the bus driver actually heard him and opened the door for him. With a muttered insult the man got off at his stop.

What I noticed, and what is the reason for my question, is that everyone near that man quite obviously felt very uncomfortable with his hollered demand. They all looked away with bland faces and ignored both his problem and his behavior. I myself always sympathize with those that cannot get off where they want to, and I felt the same helpless empathy for this man also, but at the same time the intense physicality of his shout felt inappropriate and rude, despite the fact that it was the only means for thim to assert his right to disembark. What I felt was shame.

I have been thinking about the event since then, wondering about my feelings and the discomfort I saw reflected on the faces of the other passengers. It seems to me that we expect people to quietly suffer the mistakes of others, if a polite reminder does not help, and not raise our voices beyond a certain level, like that man did. It is almost as if that man had put himself in the wrong simply by raising his voice too much.

What is the appropriate behavior in a situation like this?

*I hope that questions about commuting are allowed on this site. For many people their commute is a part of their work life, both emotionally and legally (e.g. from the perspective of many insurances). Many commuters begin to work on the train or meet colleagues on the bus, making it part of the workplace.*

Comment: Why not complain to the bus company? OR locate yourself next to the bus driver

Comment: @EdHeal Complaining to the bus company will not help you catch your train right now. And in a bus that is full not everyone can stand next to the bus driver.

Comment: If this is a common occurrence then a complaint would help. If you need to get off at a stop then moving yourself closer to the door as you approach would help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bit of a stretch even if you're a professional bus rider.

Comment: @Blrfl - What is a professional bus rider?

Comment: @EdHeal That would be the nonexistent person who's not a driver but for whom the bus is the workplace.  This isn't a question about what to do in the workplace, and the only thing that remotely ties it to that is the fact that the questioner happens to be riding the bus to work.

Comment: @Blrfl - It was a rhetorical question

Comment: @EdHeal Well, that person *was* standing close to a door. Only the bus driver didn't open it. And I'm quite sure that both the bus company and their drivers do want passengers to get off where they need to get off. A complaint will not keep drivers from forgetting the doors in the hassle of rush hour traffic, because it is human nature to make mistakes. Whatever you do to avoid or prevent such a situation, eventually it has to happen, given human fallibility. And then, *in the situation,* what is the appropriate behavior? That is the question.

Comment: Shout to be allow off is the appropriate behavior IMHO. Also a complaint will help if this is a regular occurrence. The drivers will be reminded by te powers that be.

Comment: @Blrfl Everyone on that bus is riding the bus to work. The time of the day makes it so. No school kids and no shoppers at five in the morning. And did you read the comment appended to my question? If you work on your laptop in the bus or if you discuss work with your colleagues on the bus, how is the bus *not* a workplace? Is a home office not a workplace? The workplace is everywhere where people feel that they are at work. Get on a rush hour bus and ask the people there if they consider it leisure time.

Comment: Great idea working on a bus - you are distracted and people are reading your emails etc over your shoulder. Information thieves and pick pockets must love you

Comment: @EdHeal Have you ever commuted? People here work in public transport all the time. Not everything that people do for work is sensitive. I read papers on the bus and take notes on them. Sometimes someone looks over my shoulder and talks to me about what I do and I meet new people. Very nice.

Comment: I commute everyday. I do not work on a bus. Just in case. The 1/2 to work is just time to think and read the  newspaper.

Comment: Do we have a commuting.stackexchange we could redirect this to?  Nothing workplace related here.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager [interpersonal.se].

Comment: @Dukeling Well then could someone please move the question to Interpersonal Skills? That would be very kind. Thank you

Answer (score 8):

> Is it inappropriate to shout for a bus driver to open the door during
>   commute?

No, it's not inappropriate.

If that's the only way to get the driver to open the door for you, then shout away.

And if that bothers folks near you, that's their problem.